# Printing values of type void*

Tags: c, void

In the below:

```
int cmp (void* x, void*y) {
    printf("x: %s | y: %s\n", (char*) x, (char*) y);
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char * strings[] = {"xml", "json"};
    qsort(strings, sizeof(strings), sizeof(strings[0]), cmp);
}
```

How would one see what the values of `x`,`y` are? The current approach produces gibberish such as:

> x: 2?|?? | y: 2?|??

Comment: What's wrong with what you've shown?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart updated with current output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the documentation of `qsort` again.  The arguments passed to your comparison function are not the objects to be compared, they are *pointers* to those objects.  So `x,y` are not the strings themselves (i.e. the pointers to the characters of the strings), but pointers to those pointers.

Thus you want to write

```
int cmp (void *x, void *y) {
    printf("x: %s | y: %s\n", *(char**) x, *(char**) y);
    return 0;
}
```

Also see Joshua's answer about the problem with the size arguments to `qsort`.

Finally, the `qsort` comparison function is supposed to take pointers to `const void`, not just `void`.  And it is good practice to keep things `const` when you do not intend to modify them.  In this case, you do not intend to modify the pointer that `x` points to, nor the characters that `*x` points to.   So it would be even better to write

```
int cmp (const void *x, const void *y) {
    printf("x: %s | y: %s\n", *(const char* const *) x, *(const char* const *) y);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof(strings)` does not return the number of elements in `strings` but rather something larger. Your program is undefiend. You want `sizeof(strings)/sizeof(strings[0])`.

While passing `sizeof(argv[0])` for the third argument happens to work, you really should say `sizeof(strings[0])` otherwise your code is hard to read.

The gibberish is caused by `qsort` reading out of range on array `strings` and passing wild pointers to `cmp`. Most of the nonsense is unprintable so you get lots of ? characters.

Nate Eldredge caught the other half. `a` and `b` arguments to `cmp` should be cast to `char **` not `char *`.