# Print (value of) value of void* and iterating through it

Tags: c

This is a follow u to my last question about printing a `void*` pointer, [Printing values of type void*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58045052/printing-values-of-type-void). Now I am trying to print the characters in that string. I'm able to print the first character, but am having trouble iterating through the pointer to print all the characters. How should this be done? What I have so far is:

```
int cmp (const void* x, const void* y) {

    char x_lower, y_lower;
    printf("x: %s | y: %s\n", *(char**) x, *(char**) y);

    for (int i=0; i<strlen(*(char**)x); i++) {
        printf("x: %c | y: %c\n",**(char **)(x+i),**(char **)(y+i));
    }

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char * strings[] = {"xml", "json"};
    qsort(strings, (sizeof(strings)/sizeof(strings[0])), sizeof(strings[0]), cmp);
}
```

The above gives me a seg fault.

Comment: Instead of doing `*(char**)` all over the place, you want to declare variables at the start eg `char *p1 = *(char**)x; char *p2 = *(char**)y;`. Much less opportunity for disaster this way.

Comment: As it stands, `(x + i)` will not do the pointer arithmetic properly, since x is `void *`, so for example when `i` is `1`, the result is to point to one byte later than the value of `x`. But since the actual target of the pointer is of type `char *`, ie, another pointer, which is bigger than one byte you are now pointing to the middle of the target, so you read a nonsense pointer, and when you dereference that, the memory location doesn't exist.

Comment: I think what you wanted to do was this ```*(*(char **)(x)+i)``` instead of this ```**(char **)(x+i)```

Comment: Never call strlen in a loop. Save `strlen(*(char**)x)` in a variable and use it instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My general rule of thumb is to convert the comparator arguments to local (pointer) variables of the correct type, and then use those in the rest of the function.  You can't index `void *` variables in standard C, regardless of what GCC says.  There isn't a size for the `void` it points at.

```
int cmp(const void *vp1, const void *vp2)
{
    const char *s1 = *(char **)vp1;
    const char *s2 = *(char **)vp2;

    // Following your code - but it isn't very meaningful
    printf("x: %c | y: %c\n", *s1, *s2);
    printf("x: %s | y: %s\n",  s1,  s2);

    size_t len = strlen(s1);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++)
        printf("x: %c | y: %c\n", s1[i], s2[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

That's a lot easier to understand (and write) than the contortions you were using.  There's even a moderate chance it would "work", though since all elements compare equal, the data won't be sorted in any meaningful way (one of the reasons for the comment in the code).

<sup>***Warning:** no compiler was consulted before posting this answer.*</sup>

Comment: defining it at the start is like a life-saver. Then I can actually work with the variables in a more rational/intuitive manner than trying to figure out how many asterisks need to go in every which place. Thanks for this very helpful answer